# How can I send an object with $broadcast?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
$scope.$watch('tableForm.$pristine', function (newValue) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("tableDataUpdated", 
        { state: $scope.tableForm.$pristine });
});
```

I also tried:

```
$scope.$watch('tableForm.$pristine', function (newValue) {
    var tableForm = { pristine: $scope.tableForm.$pristine };
    $rootScope.$broadcast("tableDataUpdated", tableForm);
});
```

When the tableForm `$pristine` state changes then the value of `$scope.tableForm.$pristine`  is set to `False` and this message is broadcast.

However when I try to receive the message the value of "state" is not defined:

```
$rootScope.$on("tableDataUpdated", function (args) {
    alert(args.state);
});
```

I also tried:

```
$rootScope.$on("tableDataUpdated", function (args) {
    alert(args.tableForm);
});
```

Still I seem not to be able to send the object and have it received

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That's because listener function has two arguments being passed into it, `event`, and `args`. See [the angular docs.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on)

Try:

```
$rootScope.$on("tableDataUpdated", function (event, args) {
        alert(args.state);
    });
```

Comment: This works now. Thanks very much. I wish the AngularJS docs were a bit more clear. I was trying for a long time to find some examples doing searches with $broadcast etc. I will accept the answer.