# Execute function when modal is closed (Plunker attached)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a minor bug which i am not able to fix. Here is the plunker-> http://plnkr.co/edit/D3EjXKf48Sq2vuc5MHNx?p=preview

When the user opens the modal and makes selection, he chooses to close the modal by pressing 'Ok'

At this point of time, i want to execute ExecOnModalClose() function mentioned in the controller.

So, here is the code i tried.

```
$scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
    $scope.ExecOnModalClose();
};
```

Execute this function below when user presses 'Ok' as shown above.

```
$scope.ExecOnModalClose = function() {
     console.log("Execute this after modal closes on pressing Ok"); 
}
```

Can someone please let me know how to link these two.

Comment: I just added the exact code that you said you tried and [it works perfectly.](http://plnkr.co/edit/hlQ6dOKJv9zWXfbPxvJ2?p=preview)

Comment: serious >? when i click on, i dont see anything in the console log

Comment: Yeah. Open my link, hit F12 (or Opt+Cmd+I if you're on Mac) and open the modal. Click "Ok" and "Execute this after modal closes on pressing Ok" appears in the console.

Comment: @MikeC- silly me. Tat function was inside the modal controller itself. updated the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok(); ExecOnModalClose()">OK</button>
```

**EDIT**

after the change of the original plunker, using broadcasting seems to be the working solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZrOM2au5wErWfUtX4v4?p=preview

Comment: @Zdnek- i tried this. doesnt work. can you please show me in a plunker >?

Comment: Its not as easy as it looks. The ok() function is inside the modal and adding ExecOnModalClose() function along with it wont work because the 2nd function is outside the modal controller.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was reffering to the old plunker. Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZrOM2au5wErWfUtX4v4?p=preview using event broadcasting.

Comment: Hi @Zdenek- this is a great answer. somehow i am not able to upvote this unless you edit the answer. can you edit it pls soo i can upvote ur answer

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help :)

Comment: one last query. http://plnkr.co/edit/jhNKBjqs86fjyT2n8hOE?p=preview. In this plunker, i have $scope.Send as a object. I want to transfer this value to main controller too. can you tell me how could i ?

Comment: Just pass it together with broadcast. As shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779745/how-can-i-send-an-object-with-broadcast

Comment: Thanks Zdenek. i was able to get the result with it.